# How to make an explanation text box display when a visitor hovers on an element?

Tags: javascript, html

you have all seen that explanatory text boxes that appears when the visitor hovers over specific element, I want to add something similar for the table datas on my webpage which explains what these table datas mean. However, I don't want to go through all that creating a new div with text inside, a function that displays that div and onmouseover-onmouseout events that triggers that function(Too complicated to do such a simple thing). Is there any easier and quicker way to do that? Maybe something similar to alt attribute in img tags?

Comment: @AlanOmar Yes, this is what I need. Can I customize the boxes?

Comment: you can use a tooltip for this purpose. Follow the link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do the trick with pseudo-elements and data attributes.

```css
[data-test] {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

[data-test]:hover::before {
    content: attr(data-test);
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: calc(100% + 5px);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div data-test="tootip">Hover me</div>
```

Comment: Pseudo-elements and their content property was the answer I was looking for, thank you.